# Hibernate only accepting lower case for Postgres?

Tags: hibernate

I have a problem with hibernate & Postgres

Versions
org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.1.0.Final
&
Postgres Client and Server 9.4.5

I'm using annotations and when I use Camel case I get a table not found error but when I use lower case it works without issue (I change the table name in the database to match) so

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounttype")
public class AccountType implements Serializable {...
```

works fine but

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AccountType")
public class AccountType implements Serializable {...
```

fails with a table not found error ?

Is this a known issue or is there a property I should be setting ?!

Many thanks

Comment: Apologies found the answer on the hibernate forum.  Postgres wants a single quote round the mixed case tables - ` (https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=935715) Let me know if I should just delete this simpleton's question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies found the answer on the hibernate forum. Postgres wants a single quote round the mixed case tables - ` (forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=935715)